# Is there a contradiction between 34:13 & the sunnah

Tags: quran, hadith, contradiction

Can someone explain this apparent contradiction? The verse below state that Prophet Solomon AS ordered the Jinn to make statues....

> They made for him what he willed of elevated chambers, **STATUES**, bowls like reservoirs, and stationary kettles. [We said], "Work, O family of David, in gratitude." And few of My servants are grateful. (34:13; bold and capital emphasis mine)

According to the Tanakh we know that the temple of Prophet Solomon AS contained statues and images of heavenly creatures called cherubs. Also during the Exodus the curtains of the Tabernacle were embroidered with images of cherubs. Even the lid of the Ark of the Covenant was fashioned with golden cherubs; see [Exodus 26:1](https://biblehub.com/exodus/26-1.htm) and [Exodus 37:6-9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+37%3A6-9&version=NIV)

However in the sunnah we know that making images is forbidden :

> Narrated Abu Talha:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Angels do not enter a house that has either a dog or a picture in it." ([Sahih al-Bukhari 3322 Book 59, Hadith 128](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/128))

Based on the wording of the Hadith the prohibition seems eternal. If this is the case then it is inconceivable for the previous prophets to make images. However, if we were to argue that this is an abrogation shouldn't it be appropriate to use "will no longer enter" instead of "do not enter"? Like I said the prohibition seems eternal.

If that's not enough one should see this Hadith....

> Narrated Ibn `Abbas:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) entered the Ka`ba and found in it the pictures of (Prophet) Abraham and Mary. On that he said' "What is the matter with them ( i.e. Quraish)? They have already heard that angels do not enter a house in which there are pictures; yet this is the picture of Abraham. And why is he depicted as practicing divination by arrows?" ([Sahih al-Bukhari 3351 Book 60, Hadith 31](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/31))

Pay close attention to the hadith for it reads "They have already heard", so this means they have heard of the prohibition perhaps from the Hanafiyyah i.e. monotheists of the time. So the prohibition of making images had been enforced even since the time Ibrahim AS. Hence the prohibition is eternal. Need help.

Comment: The view of most is that images were permitted then and are forbidden in our shariah because of the closeness of idolatory. Alternatively some argue that the images in 34:13 were of non-animate beings whose images are permitted (like plants). While some might argue that the prohibition in the ahadith is only on images made with the intent of idol worship.

Comment: What about the Hadith regarding Ibrahim AS and Ismail AS? It doesn't make sense for the making of images to be prohibited during their time and allowed during the time of the Jewish prophets and prohibited again in Prophet Muhammad's SAW time. Also what about the wording in the Hadith?

Comment: That hadith does not prove that images were forbidden during the time of Abraham. Even if it was forbidden then there is nothing implausible about something being abrogated then reinstated and then abrogated again according to the circumstances, Abraham's shariah was closer to ours than the Bani Israel. The wording of hadith of angels does not need to mention the previous allowance and it being eternal is something you are perceiving, not unambigous.

Comment: Your are relying on presumptions not clear evidence. The images made by the polytheists were made for the purpose of worship, and there is no disagreement that such an image has always been forbidden, on the other hand the images made for Solomon were not for the purpose of worshiping them. Similarly these images were at a place of worship, whereas there is no clear Quranic evidence that the images made for Solomon were at a place of worship.

Comment: One might say that the Qur'an is confirming those accounts within the books of Kings and Chronicles. I've already mentioned that Solomon AS with the help of the Jinn fashioned statues of cherubs for the temple. The temple which we know as Masjid al-Aqsa was a place of worship.

Comment: "They have already heard" more likely refers to the Prophet (SAW) preaching to them for 20 years. It makes no sense for it to be the Hanafiyya because they did not have any revelation to say for sure where and when the angels enter.